# Can't decrease blockquote font size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a basic page with Bootstrap and cannot make the font size of my blockquotes smaller. When I change the CSS font-size property, the margins change since they're based on it, but the size of the text itself doesn't.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/JLwGdY)

Here's the CSS applied for the blockquotes:

```
blockquote {
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 3em auto !important;
  padding: 0.35em 40px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  position: relative;
  color: #383838;
}

blockquote:before {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 10px;
  content: "\201C";
  font-size: 80px;
  /* Element with abolute positioning is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor */
  position: absolute;
  /* Offsets from edges of element's containing block, ancestor to which element is relatively positioned */
  left: -20px; /* Negative moves it left */
  top: -20px; /* Negative moves it toward top */
  color: #7a7a7a;
}

blockquote cite {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the font size of the text inside **blockquote**, You have to define font size property of the `<p>`  tag inside the **blockquote** like this

```
blockquote p {
    font-size: 0.8em !important;
}
```

> **!important** is must necessary here it will override the font-size defined in bootstrap.

you can not use **CSS** direct like this

```
blockquote {
font-size: 30px;
}
```

because this tag has it's own `font-size` property.

The relation between blockquote and p tag is [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

Comment: _“!important is must necessary here”_ - no, it’s not. The font size from the rule `.jumbotron p` simply overwrites this here, so prefixing the rule with that ancestor element class would be the (/a) proper way to do this, instead of throwing `!important` around. `.jumbotron blockquote p { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

The `blockquote` override your css, so you have to add `!important` to the difenittion.
**For Example:**

```
 font-size: 1em!important;
```

but if you want to chang the `p` tag:

```
blockquote p{
  font-size:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just because `<blockquote>` is outer element..The inner element is `<p>` so you have to apply changes to `<p>` itself.

```css
blockquote{
font-size:30px;
}
p{
font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
        <p>A wise man proportions his belief to the evidence.</p>
</blockquote>
```

Or if you want to use font-size of `blockquote`, you have to use `!important` like this:

```
blockquote{
font-size:30px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Bhuwan yes exactly...I've edited it..thanks for correcting.